# How to count the number of iterations

Tags: matlab, variables, iteration, counting

I'm working with k-means on MATLAB. To process the valid cluster, it needs to do a looping until the cluster position doesn't change any more. The looping will show the iterations process.

I want to count how many looping/iteration happens on that clustering process. Here is the snippet of looping/iteration processing part:

```
while 1,
    d=DistMatrix3(data,c);  %// calculate the distance
    [z,g]=min(d,[],2);      %// set the matrix g group

    if g==temp,             %// if the iteration does not change anymore
        break;              %// stop the iteration
    else
        temp=g;             %// copy the matrix to the temporary variable
    end
    for i=1:k
        f=find(g==i);
        if f                %// calculate the new centroid
            c(i,:)=mean(data(find(g==i),:),1);
        end
    end
end
```

All I know that I have to do is define the iteration variable, and then write the calculation part. But, where do I have to define the variable? And how?

All the answers will be so much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by your 'Looping/Iterations'?  You have two different loops (the `for` within the `while`).  Do you want to count the number of `for` loop iterations as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define before your loop, update in your loop.

```
iterations=0;
while 1,
        d=DistMatrix3(data,c);   % calculate the distance 
        [z,g]=min(d,[],2);      % set the matrix g group

        if g==temp,             % if the iteration doesn't change anymore
            break;              % stop the iteration
        else
            temp=g;             % copy the matrix to the temporary variable
        end
        for i=1:k
            f=find(g==i);
            if f                % calculate the new centroid 
                c(i,:)=mean(data(find(g==i),:),1);
            end
        end
iterations=iterations+1;

end

fprintf('Did %d iterations.\n',iterations);
```

Answer (score 2):

A Matlab [`while`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/while.html)-loop is executed until the expression is `false`. The general setup is like this:

```
while <expression>
    <statement>
end
```

If you want to count the number of times the `while` loop was entered, the easiest way is to declare a variable outside the loop and incrementing it inside:

```
LoopCounter = 0;

while <expression>
    <statement>
    LoopCounter = LoopCounter + 1;
end
```

The question whether to increment the `LoopCounter` before or after the `<statement>` depends on whether you need it to access vector entries. In that case, it should be incremented before the `<statement>` because `0` is not a valid index in Matlab.